# Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined using ramda

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ramda.js

I have the error: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined when using composition and currying with ramda.

Here is my code:

```
const changeStateOf = _.curry((stateName, stateValue) => {
  let obj = {}
  obj[stateName] = stateValue

  this.setState(obj)
})

const inputValue = (event) => {
  return event.target.value
}

const App = React.createClass({
  handleOnChange: _.compose(changeStateOf('input'), inputValue),

  /* //This is working
  handleOnChange: function(event) {
    this.setState({input: event.target.value})
  },*/

  render: function() {
    return <div>
    <input onChange={this.handleOnChange} value={this.state.input} placeholder="Add something"/>
    </div>
  }
})
```

What I tried:

1. Adding .bind(this) to handleOnChange
2. Pass this as argument in changeStateOf

I know I'm missing something but can't see where is the problem exactly.

Thank you

Comment: It looks like `onChange={this.handleOnChange.bind(this)}` should work. Is that what you tried?

Comment: Have you tried `changeStateOf('input').bind(this)` ?

Comment: Tried both onChange={this.handleOnChange.bind(this)} (which log a warning that React auto bind function for you) and handleOnChange: _.compose(changeStateOf('input'), inputValue).bind(this). But none works

Comment: @TelmanAgababov Yes, tried this also :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i guess its not working because value of `this` might be bound with `_`which you are using to call the curry function . And the curry function writes the callback using arrow syntax which automatically binds the value of `this` to `_`

Comment: i guess its not working because value of this might be bound with '_' which you are using to call the curry function . And the curry function writes the callback using arrow syntax which automatically binds the value of this to '_'

Comment: Tried removing arrow functions and using simple functions. But still not working...

Comment: did you bind the simple function with the required this??also when calling the simple function call it using the call() function

Comment: Ok, it's working now and I don't know why! I used normal function definition and it's working without bind. (Some magic is happening here...)

Comment: so if i helped you ..why do not you try upvoting

Comment: I was waiting for you to edit the response with the correct solution. Thank you

Comment: "Some magic is happening here."  See the [MDN description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), which starts, "An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax compared to function expressions and does not bind **its own this**, arguments, super, or new.target." (emphasis added.)